# Found Leaked Objects in Instruments

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ios6

Found two leaked objects `[Photo photoWithFilePath]` and `[NSURL(NSURL) path]` in Instruments

It shows 100.0% for

```
photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image6" ofType:@"png"]];
```

and

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Any ideas how to sort this out

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using ARC? Have you run the static build analyzer to see if it gives you any hints?

Comment: I m using compiler flag -fno-objc-arc to avoid it.

Comment: static analyzer is not giving me any hint at this time.

Comment: Try it with ARC and see if fixes it for you. Other than that, it's hard for us to envision where the problem is coming from with so little info. I would try doing some things like placing release statements or using a different method to see if something changes and if I get more clues.

Comment: When i double click on the leaked object to see extended detail it shows on the right and clicking on that founds this + (Photo *)photoWithFilePath:(NSString *)path {
 return [[[Photo alloc] initWithFilePath:path] autorelease];
}
 and within this it shows leak is in at return [[[Photo alloc] initWithFilePath:path] autorelease];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your comments:

That method returns an autoreleased object so I don't think its the cause of the leak. However there could be something in the way you're using photo that retains it in memory or it could be something else like the NSBundle portion. I don't think that returns an autorelease object - you may want to double check.

Comment: NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    Photo *photo;
    
    photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image0" ofType:@"png"]];
    [photos addObject:photo]; if you can tell me if there is any problem with NSBundle mainBundle